# Never terminating when solving linear Diophantine systems

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

Say I have:

$(1):$ Set of Diophantine systems where each defines a  (possibly unbounded) polyhedron.

This is solvable with existing algorithms:

$(*):$ The $(1)$ can be solved in [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org) with [integral_points_generators()](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/backend_normaliz.html) function, using the [PyNormaliz](https://pypi.org/project/PyNormaliz/) backend. - This was mentioned on MathOverflow in [the following post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342945/88524) mentioning a problem that falls into the $(1)$ category.

This should be solvable with Mathematica since it implements such algorithms:

> $(M):$ According to [Mathematics's manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html), the algorithms and procedures for solving $(1)$ should be implemented and working, where the `Reduce[]` function is given as an example that uses this.
>
> If $(1)$ is bounded, then $(M_1):$ the linked manual section "Bounded Systems of Linear Equations and Inequalities" is the case. Otherwise, the we should be in the case $(M_2):$ "Arbitrary Systems of Linear Equations and Inequalities" as titled in the linked manual. Either way, the $(1)$ should be always solvable.
>
> As far as I understood the manual.

But, for certain cases of $(1)$, when we have the unbounded case of $(1)$, then `Reduce[]` sometimes works well and finds all solutions, and sometimes it never finishes and hence fails to solve the case.

And sometimes, those failed cases (solved cases), can actually be solved (become failed), if the input to the `Reduce[]` is given differently, which is a weird inconsistency to me.

Can we circumvent this issue, or am I missing something?

I will be demonstrating this with a concrete example:

**Example of a problem that falls into $(1)$ category**

I have a concrete example of a system that falls into $(1)$ category, which is equivalent to "$d=7$ case" mentioned in the linked post $(*)$, where it was solved using SageMath for all $K$ cases that have solutions.

It is given as:

> $(S):$ The $K=(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5,k_6)$ represents fixed constants. We have:
>
> $$
> \begin{equation*}
> \begin{cases}
>  0-a_{1} + 2 c_{1} + 2 c_{2} + 2 c_{3} + c_{4} = b k_{1} \\
>  k_{1}-a_{2} + 6 c_{1} + 6 c_{2} + 6 c_{3} + 3 c_{4}  = b k_{2} \\
>  k_{2}-a_{3} + 15 c_{1} + 10 c_{2} + 7 c_{3} + 3 c_{4} = b k_{3}\\
>  k_{3}-a_{4} + 20 c_{1} + 10 c_{2} + 4 c_{3} + c_{4}  = b k_{4}\\
>  k_{4}-a_{3} + 15 c_{1} + 5 c_{2} + c_{3}  = b k_{5}\\
>  k_{5}-a_{2} + 6 c_{1} + c_{2} = b k_{6}  \\
>  k_{6}-a_{1} + c_{1} = 0
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}
> $$
>
> Where $a_1\in[1,b-1],a_2,a_3,a_4\in[0,b-1],c_1\in[1,b],c_2,c_3,c_4\in[0,b],b\ge2$.

According to $(M)$, this should be solvable in Mathematica, with `Reduce[]`? But, sometimes it fails to resolve a $K$ case (keeps running forever).

Firstly, `Reduce[]` always works when there are no solutions to find (This is for a majority of $K$ cases, since only finitely many $K$ cases actually have solutions), and outputs `False` as expected.

Secondly, it also seems to always work as expected when we have a $K$ case that leads to the the bounded case of $(1)$, and finds all of the finitely many solutions as expected $(M_1)$.

And finally, when $K$ given falls into the category of unbounded case of $(1)$, then sometimes `Reduce[]` finds all solutions with paremeterization output like expected and described in the wolfram manual $(M_2)$; But some other times, it fails to terminate in such a case, and does not produce solutions (any output at all), and keeps running *forever*.

And there are inconsistencies in these failures.

To give an example, first here is the system $(S)$ implementation as `sys[3, K]`:

```
ClearAll[a, c, b, l, x, eq, bUp, bLow, sys];
x[a_, b_, l_] := 
  Sum[a[i + 1] (b^i + b^(2 l - i)), {i, 0, l - 1}] + a[l + 1] b^l;
eq[l_] := 
  Fold[And, 
   MapIndexed[#1 == k[First[#2]] b &, 
     CoefficientList[
      x[c, b + 1, l] - x[a, b, l] + Sum[k[i] b^i, {i, 0, 2 l}], 
      b]] /. {k[0] -> 0, k[2 l + 1] -> 0}];
bUp[l_] := 
  Fold[And, 
   Join[Table[a[i + 1] < b, {i, 0, l}], 
    Table[c[i + 1] < b + 1, {i, 0, l}]]];
bLow[l_] := 
  Fold[And, 
   Join[Table[If[i == 0, a[i + 1] >= 1, a[i + 1] >= 0], {i, 0, l}], 
    Table[If[i == 0, c[i + 1] >= 1, c[i + 1] >= 0], {i, 0, l}]]];
sys[l_, K_] := 
  eq[l] && bUp[l] && bLow[l] && b >= 2 && 
   Fold[And, Table[k[i] == K[[i]], {i, 1, 2 l}]];

ClearAll[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6];
sys[3, {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6}] /. And -> List // Column
```

**Inconsistency examples**

$A)$ The example $K=(1,3,7,7,5,1)$ is not a failed case by default, the following code will terminate and output expected solutions:

```
(* r1 *) TimeConstrained[Reduce[sys[3, {1, 3, 7, 7, 5, 1}], {}, Integers], 60]
```

But for example, if either of the following two modifications are made, then it can't solve this case.

$A.1)$ If we specify variables variables `{b, a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}` instead of leaving `{}` blank, then it appears to keep running *forever* (aborts after 60 seconds), and hence fails to solve the case.

$A.2)$ It also fails if $K$ variables are not given as variables, but substituted directly into the expression. That is, the following modification is made:

```
sys[l_, K_] := (eq[l] && bUp[l] && bLow[l] && b >= 2) /. Table[k[i] -> K[[i]], {i, 1, 2 l}];
```

Where now `(* r1 *)` would appear to fail to ever terminate, and remain running forever (aborts after 60 seconds).

**Failed Examples**

$B)$ But the main issue is, that some cases of $K$ never can be solved, where as they should be solvable according to $(M),(M_2)$?

If $K$ is picked as any case from the following set:

```
Kfail = {{1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2}, {1, 4, 11, 13, 10, 3}, {1, 5, 11, 14, 10, 4}, {2,7, 10, 10, 5, 2}, {2, 7, 14, 15, 10, 3}, {2, 8, 14, 16, 10, 4}, {2,8, 18, 21, 15, 5}, {3, 9, 14, 12, 6, 1}, {3, 10, 17, 17, 10, 3}, {3, 10, 18, 18, 11, 3}, {3, 11, 21, 23, 15, 5}, {3, 11, 22, 24, 16, 5}, {3, 12, 21, 24, 15, 6}, {4, 13, 20, 19, 10, 3}, {4, 13, 21, 20, 11, 3}, {4, 14, 24, 25, 15, 5}, {4, 14, 25, 26, 16, 5}, {5, 16, 23, 21, 10, 3}, {5, 17, 27, 27, 15, 5}}
```

Then the `(* r1 *)` line equivalent input fails to terminate. For example:

```
(* r2 *)TimeConstrained[Reduce[sys[3, {1, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2}], {}, Integers], 60]
```

Never terminates (aborts after 60 seconds).

But if we fix a value of `b` in this failed example (by adding `&& b==100` for example), we can get partial solutions.

And looking at consecutive values of `b`, we see that this `(* r2 *)`  can be written in a closed form similarly to the output of `(* r1 *)`.

> But the `Reduce[]` never finds this expected closed form for case `(* r2 *)`. I do not understand why it can solve `(* r1 *)` but not `(* r2 *)` (Or any other case from the `Kfail` cases) ?
>
> What am I missing?

For comparison to `Kfail` cases, the following cases can be solved:

```
Ksolved = {{0, 2, 6, 9, 7, 3}, {1, 3, 7, 7, 5, 1}, {1, 4, 8, 9, 6, 2}, {1, 5, 9, 11, 7, 3}, {1, 5, 10, 12, 8, 3}, {1, 5, 12, 15, 11, 4}, {2, 6, 10, 9, 5, 1}, {2, 6, 11, 10, 6, 1}, {2, 7, 11, 11, 6, 2}, {2, 7, 12, 12, 7, 2}, {2, 7, 15, 16, 11, 3}, {2, 8, 13, 14, 8, 3}, {2, 8, 14, 15, 9, 3}, {2, 8, 15, 17, 11, 4}, {2, 8, 16, 18, 12, 4}, {2, 8, 17, 19, 13, 4}, {3, 9, 13, 11, 5, 1}, {3, 10, 14, 13, 6, 2}, {3, 10, 15, 14, 7, 2}, {3, 10, 16, 15, 8, 2}, {3, 11, 17, 17, 9, 3}, {3, 11, 18, 18, 10, 3}, {3, 11, 18, 19, 11, 4}, {3, 11, 19, 20, 12, 4}, {3, 11, 20, 21, 13, 4}, {3, 12, 22, 25, 16, 6}, {3, 12, 23, 26, 17, 6}, {4, 12, 16, 13, 5, 1}, {4, 12, 17, 14, 6, 1}, {4, 12, 18, 15, 7, 1}, {4, 13, 18, 16, 7, 2}, {4, 13, 19, 17, 8, 2}, {4, 13, 22, 21, 12, 3}, {4, 14, 22, 22, 12, 4}, {4, 14, 23, 23, 13, 4}, {4, 14, 24, 24, 14, 4}, {4, 14, 26, 27, 17, 5}, {4, 15, 26, 28, 17, 6}, {5, 16, 24, 22, 11, 3}, {5, 16, 25, 23, 12, 3}, {5, 17, 28, 28, 16, 5}, {5, 17, 29, 29, 17, 5}}
```

**Questions**

> $Q_1:$ Can we avoid the inconsistencies observed? (Is there "a proper way to feed expressions to `Reduce[]`", that these inconsistencies are violating?)
>
> $Q_2:$ Why is `Reduce[]` failing to solve cases from `Kfail`? Is it possible to solve these cases with `Mathematica`?

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems that this is claimed to be a linear Diophantine system. It is not. One must specifiy a value for `b` in order for it to be linear.

Comment: Why particular Mathematica functions behave as they do often is impossible to know without detailed proprietary knowledge.  I would speculate that `Reduce` calls `GroebnerBasis` to solve these problems, and this function is notoriously sensitive to the order of variables, which may well vary among A, A1 and A2 in the question.  This speculation could be tested using `Trace`, but I do not have the time to do so.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Why is it not linear in $b$? The $k_i,i\in[1,6]$ are specified constants.

Comment: `sys[3, {1, 3, 7, 7, 5, 1}]` has products of the form `b*k[j]`. Which woukld indicate, among other things, that the `k` variables are not specified.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You can assume 'k' variables are specified. My "non-linear implementation" of `sys` is the consequence of the following: Some systems that `Reduce[]` can't solve if `k` variables are directly specified, unexpectedly, can be solved by it if we instead write `b*k[j]` and add on `&&k[j]=...` into the `sys` itself. $-$ What am I missing? Can `Mathematica` solve the $(S)$ systems, where $k_i,i\in[1,6]$ are specified constants, for any such constants? Reading the manual, it appears to me that it should be able to. But, it appears it is not able in certain cases of $k_i,i\in[1,6]$.